# Is there a word for "to consider [something] a virtue"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

For example, many religious traditions consider austerity and renunciation from material pleasures a virtue. Randian libertarianism characterizes selfishness as a virtue.

To consider as divine is to *deify*, to declare as innocent is to *exonerate*, to hold as a virtue is to —?

Comment: Maybe [*exalt*?](http://www.wordnik.com/words/exalt)

Comment: I think to exalt something you have to loudly proclaim your praise, while I'm looking for something that also includes quietly believing that something is good without saying anything. (Perhaps *exonerate* was a misleading example in that respect.)

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure I agree with that. I think you can exalt something and not [extol](http://www.wordnik.com/words/extol) it.

Comment: *Ennoble*, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *simplest* solution would be to say

> Randian libertarianism *praises* selfishness.

I am thinking of the [following usage](http://www.wordnik.com/words/praise):

> Praise
>   v. To express warm approbation of, commendation for, or admiration for.
>   v. To extol or exalt; worship.

However, I will have to agree with @JLT that *extol* is probably the most appropriate word here. It is not very common and might be considered pompous in other settings but is particularly well fitted to discussion of religion.

> Randian libertarianism *extols* selfishness.

Comment: +1 for mention of *extol* and *exalt*, which are better suited.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how importunate, or vehement one is, to hold a virtue in high regard importunately or vehemently is to TOUT.

> Randian libertarianism touts selfishness as a virtue.

Or,

> A form of Christian asceticism touts mortification as a virtue.

Comment: _Tout_ carries a slight negative connotation though doesn't it? I would not use it for someone espousing an opinion that I share.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct.  "Tout" does carry some negative freight.

Answer (score 0):

One such word would be the following:

To hold a trait as a virtue is to [*honor*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honor) it.

> a : to regard or treat (someone) with admiration and respect : to regard or treat with honor
>
> b : to give special recognition to : to confer honor on

Answer (score 0):

I believe three words which come very close and have not yet been mentioned are *esteem*, *venerate*, and *revere*.